# file descriptor out of range for select - Recompile with -threaded to work around this

Tags: haskell

I had a Haskell application crash today with this error message:

```
app: file descriptor 8758616 out of range for select (0--1024).
Recompile with -threaded to work around this.
```

How can I solve this? What does -threaded mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-threaded` refers to the option passed to GHC.

If using hpack you can specify it like this:

```
executables:
  app:
    source-dirs: src
    main: Main.hs
    ghc-options: [-threaded]
```

(couldn't find any reasonable answer for this error on the first page of Google - hence this post).

Comment: This does not help in my case. Do you have any other tips?

Answer (score 1):

If you think you're already compiling with `-threaded`, you can use RTS options to verify:

```
$ ./app +RTS --info
 [("GHC RTS", "YES")
 ,("GHC version", "9.4.8")
 ,("RTS way", "rts_thr")
 ,("Build platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Build architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Build OS", "linux")
 ,("Build vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Host platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Host architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Host OS", "linux")
 ,("Host vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Target platform", "x86_64-unknown-linux")
 ,("Target architecture", "x86_64")
 ,("Target OS", "linux")
 ,("Target vendor", "unknown")
 ,("Word size", "64")
 ,("Compiler unregisterised", "NO")
 ,("Tables next to code", "YES")
 ,("Flag -with-rtsopts", "")
 ]
```

If `"RTS way"` contains `thr`, as above, you have built the binary correctly and it should not have this issue. If it doesn't, e.g. `"rts_v"` (v for vanilla), then you need to rebuild it (perhaps some recompilation avoidance didn't notice the options changed?). See [GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/runtime_control.html#getting-information-about-the-rts) for more about different RTS ways, and the other fields above.